# Openfire websocket memory leak

Tags: java, openfire

My openfire server chat reach high CPU and RAM.

It becomes bigger time by time.

It is 4579MB RAM (openfire process 41.3%) at this time, but after 5 minutes, it will be 4600MB (41.5%). Bigger then bigger.

And it will reach ~100% RAM usage at the next morning.

I just used room chat feature.

Concurency ~600 at day, ~300 at night.

Connection timeout 30 min.

Openfire version: 4.2.1

What's my problem? How can I resolve it?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Your problem sounds like a memory leak possibly. You can attach a heap analyser and find out where the problem may lay.

Answer (score 1):

Openfire is written in Java. Java's memory management works in a way that is not compatible with how you analyzed your system. Java's memory usage can be expected to grow over time, up until it uses up a significant amount of memory that is available to it. Only then, a memory cleanup (garbage collect) will take place.

From what you wrote, it is not clear that you actually are experiencing a memory leak. Garbage collections can be infrequent: 5 minutes is not nearly enough time to observer a memory leak.

To get some kind of indication, try observing your process for a number of days. If you see a steady increase in memory usage, when usage patterns are not changed, then you can carefully assume that a memory leak might be present. If you get to that level, you'll need specialized tooling to inspect the state of the Java heap.